# wrap the contents of a tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm tring to wrap the contents of a tag with BeautifulSoup.
This:

```
<div class="footnotes">
    <p>Footnote 1</p>
    <p>Footnote 2</p>
</div>
```

should become this:

```
<div class="footnotes">
  <ol>
    <p>Footnote 1</p>
    <p>Footnote 2</p>
  </ol>
</div>
```

So I use the following code:

```
footnotes = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "footnotes" })
footnotes_contents = ''
new_ol = soup.new_tag("ol") 
for content in footnotes[0].children:
    new_tag = soup.new_tag(content)
    new_ol.append(new_tag)

footnotes[0].clear()
footnotes[0].append(new_ol)

print footnotes[0]
```

but I get the following:

```
<div class="footnotes"><ol><
    ></
    ><<p>Footnote 1</p>></<p>Footnote 1</p>><
    ></
    ><<p>Footnote 2</p>></<p>Footnote 2</p>><
></
></ol></div>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Is it okay if I try this for you using lxml ?

Comment: Yes please. No problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using lxml:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import lxml.builder as builder
E = builder.E

doc = LH.parse('data')
footnote = doc.find('//div[@class="footnotes"]')
ol = E.ol()
for tag in footnote:
    ol.append(tag)
footnote.append(ol)
print(LH.tostring(doc.getroot()))
```

prints

```
<html><body><div class="footnotes">
    <ol><p>Footnote 1</p>
    <p>Footnote 2</p>
</ol></div></body></html>
```

Note that with `lxml`, an Element (tag) can be in only one place in the tree (since every Element has only one parent), so appending `tag` to `ol` also removes it from `footnote`. So unlike with BeautifulSoup, you do not need to iterate over the contents in reverse order, nor use `insert(0,...)`. You just append in order.

---

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
import bs4 as bs
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(f)

footnote = soup.find("div", { "class" : "footnotes" })
new_ol = soup.new_tag("ol")

for content in reversed(footnote.contents):
    new_ol.insert(0, content.extract())

footnote.append(new_ol)
print(soup)
```

prints

```
<html><body><div class="footnotes"><ol>
<p>Footnote 1</p>
<p>Footnote 2</p>
</ol></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just move the *`.contents`* of your tag over using [`tag.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract); don't try to create them anew with `soup.new_tag` (which only takes a *tag name*, not a whole tag object). Don't call `.clear()` on the original tag; `.extract()` already removed the elements.

Move items over *in reverse* as the contents are being modified in-place, leading to skipped elements if you don't watch out.

Finally, use `.find()` when you only need to do this for one tag.

You do need to create a copy of the `contents` list, as it'll be modified in place

```
footnotes = soup.find("div", { "class" : "footnotes" })
new_ol = soup.new_tag("ol")

for content in reversed(footnotes.contents):
    new_ol.insert(0, content.extract())

footnotes.append(new_ol)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class="footnotes">
...     <p>Footnote 1</p>
...     <p>Footnote 2</p>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> footnotes = soup.find("div", { "class" : "footnotes" })
>>> new_ol = soup.new_tag("ol")
>>> for content in reversed(footnotes.contents):
...     new_ol.insert(0, content.extract())
... 
>>> footnotes.append(new_ol)
>>> print footnotes
<div class="footnotes"><ol>
<p>Footnote 1</p>
<p>Footnote 2</p>
</ol></div>
```

Comment: @lorussian: fixed; I had it working, but then my copy-and-paste demo-in-progress had a small mistake in it and I missed that as other things distracted me from actually verifying the last crucial step: rereading the post.