# Adding missing HTML elements using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

If I was given a string with the following HTML tags

```
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 2</li>
<li>List Item 3</li>
```

How would I go about adding `<ul>` tags around the list items so that the HTML is valid.

I'm aware of libraries such as BeautifulSoup however from looking at the documentation, there doesn't appear to be any sort of solution. I'm aware I could use Regex however I'm not 100% how I would implement this since the number of `<li>` tags can be infinite and can contain children.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit:**

The HTML given isn't only:

```
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 2</li>
<li>List Item 3</li>
```

but contains other tags, that bit above is only a fragment of what the HTML string will look like. The string will not be the same either, it's based on user input meaning it could be anything that contains `<li>` without a correct `<ul>` element as the list item's parent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633963/402197

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you need is something like this:

```
lis = """
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 2</li>
<li>List Item 3</li>"""

ul = '<ul>{}</ul>'.format(lis)
```

To remove `\n` from your `li` elements, you can use:

```
ul = '<ul>{}</ul>'.format(''.join(li.strip('\n') for li in lis))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> ul
'<ul><li>List Item 1</li><li>List Item 2</li><li>List Item 3</li></ul>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately I don't think I was clear enough, I just updated the question to reflect what I'm trying to get.